# How can I find what is sending out a confirm?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, developer-tools

I have an issue with a server I'm working with, and I need to figure out where a certain error is coming from. Specifically, I would like to know what script is having trouble. I get three consecutive `confirm` boxes alerting me of an error and asking if I want to continue when a certain part of a page starts to load.

Is there a way I can figure out where those are coming from, specifically within the Chrome Developer tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rightclick on your page, click "select element" and then take the console tab.

[image: Developer console]

It will show u errors that have happened on this page and its source (bottom left). Click on that source to see the lines where the error was detected.
Excuse my not-so-decent drawing skills :)

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at that, but there are 100 errors coming from everywhere I because it is a tad outdated. I need to be able to filter the unimportant errors from the important ones. The "Console" page is chock full of errors already with no indicators of how important they are to the piece I care about. The only real hard evidence I have of where the trouble is comes from those three "confirms". I need to track which script that is being launched by, and when.

Comment: Well, thats not a good sign. But if you notice the small Y icon in top left, this can be used to filter e.g. only real errors out.

Comment: Right, and I have that on. But a "unsafe UserAgent header" is just as much an error to the computer as a "Script did not load".

Comment: Well I dont know your project so I'll have to give a shot in the dark: Try entering .js in the filter menu to see only errors occuring from .js files. In Internet Explorer, you will have a popup that will tell you the line right away, if your bug is multibrowser compatible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to do it that way. A bit slow, but, hey, I've got all night.